# How to share Swagger documentation

Tags: javascript, api, rest, documentation, swagger

I recently started using Swagger for my documentation but there are few things that are still unclear to me. I created my YAML document and now I would like to be able to share my documentation in a .pdf or HTML/Javascript page with the rest of my team. I can't use SwaggerHub because they don't have private repositories and Swagger Editor doesn't appear to allow to share the panel on the right.

Just to be clear, I would like to be able to get something like:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm biased as I work on swaggerhub, but that's what the project is for:

https://swaggerhub.com

From there, you can push your swagger specs automatically to github and also make other users collaborators on the API (or just read-only).

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to collaborate with another company but only have the basic four licence Team arrangement. It is a product we are developing so my API has to be private. I am using SwaggerHub but was disappointed to see that users can only see my private APIs if they are "collaborators" and hence covered by a paid licence (you can easily share public APIs on SwaggerHub). I guess this will mean hosting the HTML doco (which you can download from your SwaggerHub API) in my own Cloud-hosted instance of Swagger UI and securing it behind a logon...Open to suggestions!