# How to share swagger documentation between git repositories

Tags: git, swagger

I have many projects, hosted in different git repositories, and I would like to know how I could put my swagger documentation on git.

I use this swagger documentation to generate classes in java and in angular.

I don't want to put the documentation in every project, I would like to have something like svn:externals link. At least a good practice to deal with it.

I already saw this post : [How to share Swagger documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357160/how-to-share-swagger-documentation), but it doesn't answer my question.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "Swagger documentation" - just the API definition file (YAML/JSON), or Swagger UI webpage + assets, or both, or something else?

Comment: I mean just the api (yaml/json file).

Comment: Something like Git submodules? See [SVN:externals equivalent in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/571232/113116) and [GitHub include from another repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17775828/113116)

Comment: Well I have been looking at it, but if I have many api file, I just want one file, not all of them. Do you have an idea to select some files ?